# YII ckeditor image upload

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor, fckeditor

Im using ckeditor widget in yii

recently I moved server,  from that time onwards I'm getting this error while try to upload images.

**URL requested**:

http://test.com/assets/b0f76821/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init&type=Images&langCode=en

**Server response:**

Status: 500

**Response text:**

```
<html><head><title>Error 500 - Internal Server Error</title><head><body><h1>Error 500 - Internal Server Error</h1><p>An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.</p></body></html>
```

plz help me what i have to do.

Comment: Are you sure that the url, and the domain, are correct?

Comment: the url is http://mysiteurl.com/assets/b0f76821/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init&type=Images&langCode=en editor is working fine.but using editor if i try to upload image its showing that error.

Comment: Since the assets are dynamically generated on runtime, did you try to empty the assets directory and the the system renew them?

Comment: yes i did like that and after that i reinstalled ckfinder.still same problem.

Comment: what are the other possibilities

Comment: is there any permissions required from server